# Python Programming with SQL debugging error

Tags: python, sql

Here is my part of code:

```
#
# Database access functions for the web forum.
# 

import time

## Database connection
DB = []

## Get posts from database.
def GetAllPosts():
    '''Get all the posts from the database, sorted with the newest first.

    Returns:
      A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary has a 'content' key
      pointing to the post content, and 'time' key pointing to the time
      it was posted.
    '''
    DB = phycopg2.connect("dbname=forum")
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("selece time, content from posts order by time desc")
    posts = ({'content': str(row[1], 'time': str(row[0])} for row in c.fetchall())
    DB.close()
    #posts = [{'content': str(row[1]), 'time': str(row[0])} for row in DB]
    #posts.sort(key=lambda row: row['time'], reverse=True)
    return posts

## Add a post to the database.
def AddPost(content):
    '''Add a new post to the database.

    Args:
      content: The text content of the new post.
    '''
    DB = phycopg2.connect("dbname=forum")
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("insert into posts (content) values (%s)",(content,))
    DB.commit()
    #t = time.strftime('%c', time.localtime())
    #DB.append((t, content))
```

This is linked with another file forum.py

When I run it, following error occur:

> File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\fsnd-virtual-machine\FSND-Virtual-Machine\vagrant\forum\forumdb.py",
>   line 22
>       posts = ({'content': str(row[1], 'time': str(row[0]))}
>                                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You have `selece` instead of `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Typo on the `selece time, content from posts order by time desc`. Should be

```
## Get posts from database.
def GetAllPosts():
    '''Get all the posts from the database, sorted with the newest first.

    Returns:
      A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary has a 'content' key
      pointing to the post content, and 'time' key pointing to the time
      it was posted.
    '''
    DB = phycopg2.connect("dbname=forum")
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("select time, content from posts order by time desc")
    posts = ({'content': str(row[1], 'time': str(row[0])} for row in c.fetchall())
    DB.close()
    #posts = [{'content': str(row[1]), 'time': str(row[0])} for row in DB]
    #posts.sort(key=lambda row: row['time'], reverse=True)
    return posts
```